# ipywidgets: How to observe state change in Box children?

Tags: ipywidgets

I have a class (inherited from `Box`) with children widgets, and I'd like to call observe on the box, so that I can register a callback if there's a change made to any of its children.

Of course, I can I call `box.child1.observe`, `box.child2.observe`, `box.child3.child1.observe`, etc., but I have nested boxes and I don't want to have to enumerate through every leaf widget.  I would prefer to simply call `box.observe` from that box's parent.

How can I modify my box class so that a change to its children notifies a change to the box itself?  As of now, if I register a callback with `box.observe(func, 'value')`, then `func` never gets called.  How to fix?  Thanks.

Comment: you would need to subclass `Box`, and override the observe method to set observe on all the child elements too. 

Note this would only work on the current children when you set `box.observe`, if you added more child elements later on, without re-setting `box.observe` then only the original box children would have the desired behaviour.

Comment: @ac24 Thanks for the suggestion. I inherited from `Box` but had to override `box._observe` to call `child._add_notifiers` on each of the `Box` children.